# get multidimensionnel array keys

Tags: php, arrays

This also sounds simple but I can not. How to recover the word "SALUT"

```
$din = array
    (
        "SALUT" => array
            (
                "A",
                "B",
                "C",
                "D",
                "E",
                5 => array
                    (
                        "T",
                        "W",
                        "JO",
                        "X",
                        "O"
                    )
            ),
        "Y",
        "V",
        "I",
        "G",
        "Y" => array
            (
                "S",
                "D",
                "G",
                "V",
                "O"
            ),
        "H",
        "O",
        "P"
    );
```

Comment: `$salut = array_keys($din)[0];`

Comment: thanks you my brother.

Comment: simple just `array_keys($din)` and then collect the value.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use array_keys and then collect the value.

```
$keys = array_keys($din);
```

After this you wil get the like array below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SALUT
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3
    [5] => Y
    [6] => 4
    [7] => 5
    [8] => 6
)
```

Now you need to collect:

```
echo $din_key = $keys[0]; //SALUT
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However I have another little problem. in the following table, I would be able to recover all parent keys to CHILD2 key as a text. example: parent1-parent2 .....

Comment: '$d = array
    (
        "PARENT1" => array
            (
                "FOO",
                "PARENT2" => array
                    (
                        "CHILD1",
                        "CHILD2",
                    )
            )
    );'

Comment: you mean `SALUT, 5, Y`??